# Wrong type assertion on union

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-assertion

I do not understand why the type assertion is not working in this minimum reproducible example.

Here is the [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhzAgJygXigIgIIagH0wCEMAoE0SKAVQGcIAbCGmtKAbwF8yLoBhAewB2wAIYBLQcgA8AFQB8aElGXU6jZviUq2WlSp4AuTAGMhoiclJ69ANxH0ArhCMzdULiQBmDwceBihKGAkEUEaT34kAFspAA0oCAAPREEAExY4BGQAGigATQTkiDSM+EQkOQAKU2FxSSQjAVqLJDj8fLkASiMRZmRgFhrzeqgxFibh6ViFHT0AejmoYwcaYH4oqHp+AHMxYxIPRmAlszrkRtOWqWxcAgxiBXQfVIhPC1SoXs-BEDIFqCwfSQAyggn4UEI5BCYQi0WuOFy9wwVSGZyQnTIqJaUH+EzR8NuRGRbmsOMWeKuNwUAHcABbFVQMJgsMYnKJRYqIVIk6z-ACSUGpoWOFPqBLkQA)

```js
type Letter = "A" | "B"

type Useless = {}

type Container<T> =
    Useless |
    {
        type: "container"
        value: T
    }

function transform<X extends Letter, Y extends Letter>(container: Container<X | Y>): asserts container is Container<X> {
    // custom logic
}

let container: Container<"A" | "B"> = undefined as any

// Asserts no B
transform<"A", "B">(container)

container // Container<"A" | "B">
          // Container<"A"> when Useless is commented
          // I want Container<"A">
```

I want *container* to have type `Container<"A">`.

When I remove the type *Useless* altogether, then it works as expected.

When I replace type *Useless* by `type Useless = { key: string }`, my container has type *Useless* instead of `Container<"A">`.

How can I obtain the type `Container<"A">`?

Answer (score 0):

im actually not super sure why typescript has some problems here i assume the union with a generic where the T has no affect sometimes trips it up

if you split it up it works for me. i assume here that `Useless` always asserts?

```js
type Letter = "A" | "B"

type Useless = {}

type Container<T> =
    {
        type: "container"
        value: T
    }

type Input<T> = Useless | Container<T>

function transform<X extends Letter, Y extends Letter>(container: Input<X | Y>): asserts container is Container<X> {
    // custom logic
}

let container: Input<"A" | "B"> = undefined as any

// Asserts no B
transform<"A", "B">(container)

container // Container<"A" | "B">
          // Container<"A"> when Useless is commented
          // I want Container<"A">
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=103&pln=13&pc=112#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhzAgJygXigIgIIagH0wCEMAoE0SKAVQGcIAbCGmtKAbwF8yLoBhAewB2wAIYBLQcgA8AFQB8aElGXslK9TwBcmAMZDRE5KXXqAbiPoBXCNplrlXcuGgBJQWEvBZC9LQZMWAgFhcUkkbzIAM0tBHWAxIShgJBFBGkj%20JABbKQANKAgAD0RBABMWOARkABooAE0C4ogyivhEJDkACj0QwyRtNw8vfII6uQBKbRFmZGAWHoMwqDEWYMXpXIU2eygAel2oHUsaYH4sqHp%20AHMxHRJHRmBD-VDkAfdPKWxcAgxiHygMVKEEihlKUGmEMEIDI%20ygWBmSDmUEE-CghHIKTSGWyXxwtT%20GC6C1eSHGZBJfT2BzWpLxPyIRJ2JmpUFpfXpCgA7gALZrUOiMZjLeZnLLNRClZkmOEuKBc1JPdlhTlAA)